# Invisibile ListView items [Release APK]

Tags: android, listview, proguard

I have a `ListView` of items. In `Debug` mode I am able to see all items of `ListView` but when I generate a release APK, all items of ListView are invisible but still clickable, just item's text is invisible. when I disable **pro guard** everything works fine. I using Gson to convert JSON to java object.

**PROGUARD**:

```
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

**UPDATE:**

**Helper:**

```
public class PlazaHelper {
    public static List<PlazaModel> retrievePlazaHelper(Context context) {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.nightwaveplazalinks));
        return (new Gson()).fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<PlazaModel>>() {
        }.getType());
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class PlazaModel {

    private String name;

    @SerializedName("stream")
    private String url;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class PlazaListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<PlazaModel> PlazaModels;

    public PlazaListAdapter(Activity activity, List<PlazaModel> PlazaModels) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.PlazaModels = PlazaModels;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PlazaModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return PlazaModels.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_style, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(holder);

        }
        PlazaModel plazaModel = (PlazaModel) getItem(position);
        if (plazaModel == null) {
            return view;
        }
        holder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        holder.text.setText(plazaModel.getName());
        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            text = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You should **`keep`** the names of all public classes in the specified package & its
>   subpackages.

```
-keep class packageName.subPackageName.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @IntelliJ Amiya ,but still i can't see the items

Comment: `-keep class packageName.subPackageName.** { *; }` solved my problem ,thank you